# transform point to another coordinate

Tags: geometry, transform

suggest here are 3 points on,(x0,y0),(x1,y1),(x2,y2)

```
O = (x0,y0)
e1 = (x1-x0,y1-y0)
e2 = (x2-x0,y2-y0)
```

3 can make a new cordinate (O,e1,e2)

here's a point (x,y)

how to calculate the point location in (O,e1,e2)?please write down the formula ,thanks.

once i remember,but now i forget.

Comment: It seems that **is** already the formula, what else do you need?

Comment: @martinstoeckli i couldn't find the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call new coordinates `a` and `b`.

In the old coordinate system the point will be `O+a*e1+b*e2`. Since it should be the same point `(x,y)`, we have two linear equations:

```
x=Ox+a*e1x+b*e2x
y=Oy+a*e1y+b*e2y
```

Everything except `a` and `b` is known, two unknowns, two equations - solution exists if e1 and e2 are not parallel.

The system can be solved either by inversion of matrix `( (e1x,e2x) , (e1y,e2y) )`, or by expressing `a` in terms of `b` from the first equation and substituting it into the second one.

Comment: You should probably add that you can easily use matrix inversion to solve this!